# postgres pg_dump + .pgpass file : no password supplied

Tags: postgresql, backup, psql, pg-dump

per PSQL docs I created a `.pgpass` file on macOS with `0600` mask.

```
a.b.com:32109:mydb:user1:password1
```

when I list the file:

```
$ ls -la .pgpass
-rw-------  1 user  staff  212 Dec 21 12:56 .pgpass
```

```
export PGPASSFILE=.pgpass ; export PGSSLROOTCERT=development-pg-cert ; export  PGSSLMODE=verify-full ; pg_dump -w --host=a.b.com --port=32109  --file=2022_12_21_12_56-development/2022_12_21_12_56-development.dmp

pg_dump: error: connection to server at "a.b.com" (151.236.101.232), port 32109 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

```
$ hexdump -C .pgpass
00000000  2a 3a 33 32 31 30 39 3a  6d 79 64 62 3a 75 73 65  |*:32109:mydb:use|
00000010  72 31 3a 70 61 73 73 77  6f 72 64 31              |r1:password1|
0000001c
```

note: I can connect to the database and list tables with no issues with the CLI. if I remove the `-w` flag from `pg_dump` : it will ask me for password prompt . as if it doesn't read the pgpass file at all.
what can be the problem ?

Comment: Try typing name of database in pg_dump parameters. or add a line for postgresql database in .pgpass file

Comment: You are not providing a username for pg_dump so it will take the name of the current operating system user. Are those two the same?

Comment: not only I didn't provide `--username` I also forgot about the `--dbname` . all the parameters are required except for the password. it is just badly documented . thankfully I solved it few minutes after posting the question. thanks everyone who helped here.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems the `.pgpass` file is used quite differently than what I expected. the first 4 fields (`a.b.com:32109:mydb:user1`) are not used as override input for the executable.

it it used for pattern matching and selection ( yes , `.pgpass` may contain multiply lines).
you must provide pg_dump the `--host, --port, --dbname, --username` as usuall. you omit the password parameter.

Then:  `pg_dump` will scan the parameters and compare it to the `.pgpass` content for regex matching. If the hostname matches `--host` and the port matches --port and dbname match...  only then it will use the provided password in this file.

if something doesn't match , the executable will completely ignore the `.pgpass` line . you will need to manually type in password.

if you want to do more relaxed pattern matching, you can put in the `.pgpass` file `*` in the relevant section.

the same file-2-parameters match works with `psql` executable.